# Using javascript to change html using react.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to read an HTML file (client.html) and then listen on **port 8000**.
In that html file I also have a `<script = "client.js"></script>` tag so that I can use `react.js` (without jsx) to alter the HTML. Until now I have been able to establish a server but no matter how I change the `client.js` file the changes don't seem to show on ***http://localhost:8000/client.html.***

**server.js**

```js
//server.js
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./client.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }       
    http.createServer( async (request, response) => {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(8000,() => console.log("started.."));
});`
```

**client.js**

```js
//client.js
class Hello extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return React.createElement('div', null, `Hello ${this.props.toWhat}`);
      }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Hello, {toWhat: 'World'}, null),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<!-- client.html -->
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <p>helloworld</p>
  <!-- <script src="lib.js"></script> -->
  <script src="client.js"></script> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some modifications in your server.js.

```
var http = require("http"),
fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");

http
   .createServer(function(request, response) {
      var filePath = "." + request.url;
      if (filePath == "./") filePath = "./client.html";

      var extname = path.extname(filePath);
      var contentType = "text/html";
      switch (extname) {
        case ".js":
          contentType = "text/javascript";
          break;
        case ".css":
          contentType = "text/css";
          break;
        case ".json":
          contentType = "application/json";
          break;
      }

      fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
        response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": contentType });
        response.end(content, "utf-8");
      });
    })
   .listen(8000, () => console.log("started..."));
```

Basically, you need to handle the **.js** files in your node server.
Reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Node_server_without_framework